# Use scipy.stats to estimate probability

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I have a question where:-

1. the probability of answering question correctly is 90%,
2. there are 50 true/false questions to the exam, and
3. estimate the probability that no more than 4 questions will be answered incorrectly in the exam.

The solution for this question in R is:-
pnorm(4.5, m=5, s=sqrt(4.5)

Is there anybody who can provide the solution to this problem in Python? I have looked through numerous stackoverflow posts and have been unable to find what I am looking for.

I have looked through stackoverflow, have done a search on the internet, and have looked through scipy documentation, but I am unable to find anything that will help me to solve this probability problem in Python.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: `from scipy.stats import norm`
`norm.cdf( 4.5, 5, (4.5)**0.5)`

Comment: Ta very much. It gave the same return as what was in R.