# Answer to a probability distribution of sample proportion question in Python

Tags: python, r, scipy

I have a question that I am unanble to answer:-

1. 18% of Americans live below the poverty line
2. Select a sample of 10 people in the US
3. what is the probability that more than 20% of the sample live below the poverty line?

The solution to this problem in R is:-

1-pnorm(0.2, m=0.18, s=sqrt(0.01476))

If anybody can help me to translate the solution to this problem to Python I would really appreciate it.

I have tried to use scipy.stats.norm to solve this problem with no success, as I am not sure what values to place within the brackets.

I have searched the internet and stackoverflow and am unable to find a question and solution that fits my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "The solution to this problem in R is:- 1-pnorm(0.2, m=0.18, s=sqrt(0.01476))".  No, it isn't.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please can you give me the solution? Many thanks for this.

Comment: If I *gave* you the solution to your question, I would simply allow you to get a good mark in your assesment.  If I *show* you how to get the correct answer, I teach you how to answer this question and every other similar question you might encounter (including your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74320798/use-scipy-stats-to-estimate-probability)).

Comment: The probability that r out of n people/items have a given binary trait is a *Binomial* random variable, not a *Normal* random variable.  In R, you can generate a sample from a binomial distribution with the `rbin` function.  To work out the probability that at least 10% of the sample have the trait, you need to work out p(R=r) for r=0, ..., n.  In your case 10% of the sample equates to r=2.  So sum p(R=r) for r=2, ..., n.  The function you need has a name similar to `rbin`.  If it also has a parameter named `lower.tail`, you may be heading in the right direction.

Comment: I am not a student. I am studying statistics and probability and would like to translate the code from R to Python. Thank you for your comments anyway.